# How can I display an Ascii File in a Web Browser?

Tags: html, text, web

I have a website. I have uploaded some `.c` and `.py` files to my website. Now, if I have a `.txt` file, then I can open it directly in a new tab in the browser. However, to view my `.c` and `.py` files, which are in ASCII format, I have to download them and use a local text-editor to view them. This seems impractical.

How can I view the plaintext of my `.c` and `.py` files in the browser? Is this something I can configure on the web-end, or is this an option I have to set in my browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access of your web server (in case of apache web server) settings, Then you can do it.

Put following lines in apache2.conf (Ubuntu/Debian) / httpd.conf (Redhat/Fedora)

```
AddType text/plain .c
AddType text/plain .py
```

and restart the web server

Comment: Is there anything I can do if I don't have server-access?

Comment: As it is determined by web server, which mime-type should be set for specific file type. So I am not sure if anything else you can do it.

Comment: Depending on server settings, you may or may not be able to set such things on a per-directory basis, e.g. using a `.htaccess` file in the top-level directory of your web pages.